# Watson Visual Recognition - Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am trying to use the Watson Visual Recognition service with the watson-developer-cloud NPM module. But I always get the following error. What am I doing wrong?

```
 Unauthorized: Access denied due to invalid credentials.
```

I already searched for hours and found many people with the same problem, but none of the answers resolved the issue.

My service authentication informations (just test data):

```
 {
   "apikey": "API_KEY",
   "iam_apikey_description": "...",
   "iam_apikey_name": "...",
   "iam_role_crn": "...",
   "iam_serviceid_crn": "...",
   "url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api"
 }
```

My Node.js code to create the VisualRecognizionV3 object:

```
 let visualRecognition = new VisualRecognizionV3({
     api_key: "API_KEY",
     version: "2018-03-19"
 });
```

I will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to specify the api_key with the `iam_apikey` parameter name, like this:

`let visualRecognition = new VisualRecognizionV3({
     iam_apikey: "API_KEY",
     version: "2018-03-19"
 });`

See the doc [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk#supplying-the-iam-api-key)

Comment: I thought I tried that already... But it worked when I tried "again" now. Must have made a mistake at the first time. Thank you anyway!