# Watson Visual Recognition API C# Authorisation

Tags: c#, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

Trying to get Watson Visual Recognition working with C# but I am getting an unauthorised error when attempting to classify an image through the API. The credentials I'm using are the "Auto-generated service credentials".

The error that I am receiving is:
ServiceResponseException: The API query failed with status code Unauthorized: Unauthorized

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string versionDate = "2018-03-19";
        string endpoint = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api";

        VisualRecognitionService visualRecognition = new VisualRecognitionService(apiKey, versionDate);
        visualRecognition.SetEndpoint(endpoint);

        // throws error here
        var result = visualRecognition.Classify(url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg/1023px-Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg"); 
    }
}
```

Also, let me know if I can provide anymore information that might help

Comment: Can you try with url: https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api

Comment: Also, need to escape '/' with '//' in url: https://upload.wikimedia.org//wikipedia//commons//thumb//d//d9//Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg//1023px-Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have found a solution.
@Gauravsa that url changes the error to Forbidden: Unauthorized.
Wasn't necessary to escape '/' in the url, but I would imagine that it is good practice to do so. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution after looking at this answer for a node.js implementation:
[Watson Visual Recognition - Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746269/watson-visual-recognition-unauthorized/51758093)

The issue was that I needed to use Iam Api Key for authentication, which can be done like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string versionDate = "2018-03-19";
        string endpoint = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api";

        VisualRecognitionService visualRecognition = new VisualRecognitionService(apiKey, versionDate);
        visualRecognition.SetEndpoint(endpoint);

        // updated to include token options with Iam Api Key
        TokenOptions options = new TokenOptions
        {
            IamApiKey = apiKey
        };
        visualRecognition.SetCredential(options);
        // end edit

        var result = visualRecognition.Classify(url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg/1023px-Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue